# C ++ Error: variable-sized object may not be initialized?

Tags: c++, graphics

I have been trying to figure out why i'm getting an initialization error:

```
int size = polygons[polyID].n;
    Clipper clipper = Clipper();
    Vertex tmp[50];
    size = clipper.clipPolygon(polygons[polyID].n, polygons[polyID].p, tmp, CWll, CWur);
    int x[size] = {};
    int y[size] = {};
```

and the error I am getting is:

```
Pipeline.cpp:89:8: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
        int x[size] = {};
              ^~~~
Pipeline.cpp:90:8: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
        int y[size] = {};
```

Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this issue?

Comment: So the size is not constant?

Comment: You are attempting to initialize a variable length array. The compiler has no clue how long this array will be and cannot generate the appropriate code. This is but one of the many reasons the variable length arrays are not part of Standard C++.

Comment: C++, and what is a workaround to variable length arrays in c++?

Comment: `std::vector<int> y(size);` will make a dynamic array of size `size` with all the values initialized to 0.

Comment: Documentation on `std::vector`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector